# How to change an element of a tuple?

Tags: python

How to change the third element of the second nested tuple into char 7?
Possibly, with minimal wasted memory, how to transform this tuple:

```
data7=(('1','2','3','4'),'A',('5','6','6','8'),'B',('9','10','11','12'))
```

So it outputs:

```
(('1','2','3','4'),'A',('5','6','7','8'),'B',('9','10','11','12'))
```

Comment: tuples are immutable, if you need to mutate them why not use a list instead? This will be memory efficient

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559217/python-update-a-value-in-a-list-of-tuples) answer your question?

Comment: You can only reconstruct the data structure from scratch with changed data

Comment: Strings are immutable in C++ and C# and obviously strings are also the building block of all programs and whole computer age. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things about tuples is that they are immutable. You should use them to store constants and other stuff which won't be changed in order to improve your performance.

If there is a need of changing items of a tuple you should really consider switching to lists.

Answer to your question:

```
data7=(('1','2','3','4'),'A',('5','6','6','8'),'B',('9','10','11','12'))
data = list(data7)
item = list(data[2])
item[2] = '7'
data[2] = tuple(item)
data7 = tuple(data)
```

As far as I am concerned, the memory usage won't be too big, since python doesn't allocate new memory for every tuple item.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, and assuming you have a nested structure of tuples and other objects on the first level, and objects in the inner tuples:

```
# generator to enumerate the inner tuples
# similar to the builtin enumerate but only enumerates tuples
# yields None if not a tuple
def enumerate_tuples(iterable, start=0):
    for item in iterable:
        if isinstance(item, tuple):
            yield start, item
            start += 1
        else:
            yield None, item

# faking mutation of a tuple by generating a new tuple on the fly
def change_tuple(inpt, n_tuple, n_elem, new_val):
    return tuple(tuple(new if j==n_elem else item
                       for j, item in enumerate(t, start=1)
                       ) if i==n_tuple else t
                 for i, t in enumerate_tuples(inpt, start=1))

change_tuple(data7, 2, 3, '7')
# (('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'A', ('5', '6', '7', '8'), 'B', ('9', '10', '11', '12'))

change_tuple(data7, 1, 1, 'X')
# (('X', '2', '3', '4'), 'A', ('5', '6', '6', '8'), 'B', ('9', '10', '11', '12'))

change_tuple(data7, 99, 99, 'X',)
# (('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'A', ('5', '6', '6', '8'), 'B', ('9', '10', '11', '12')), '7')
```

Note that it only enumerates the tuples:

```
data8 = (('1','2','3','4'),'A', 'B', 'C', ('5','6','6','8'), 'D', ('9','10','11','12'))
change_tuple(data8, 2, 3, '7')
# (('1', '2', '3', '4'),
#  'A',
#  'B',
#  'C',
#  ('5', '6', '7', '8'),     # second tuple
#  'D',
#  ('9', '10', '11', '12'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic function following a chain of indeces and setting the value there. Since this can handle immutable objects, it returns a new object:

```
def change_obj(obj, val, *indexes):
    if not indexes:
        return val
    index, *rest = indexes
    t = type(obj)
    if isinstance(obj, tuple):
        obj = list(obj)
    obj[start] = change_obj(obj[index], val, *rest)
    return t(obj)
    
>>> change_obj(data7, "7", 2, 2)
(('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'A', ('5', '6', '7', '8'), 'B', ('9', '10', '11', '12'))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
data7 = (('1', '2', '3', '4'), 'A', ('5', '6', '6', '8'), 'B', ('9', '10', '11', '12'))

modified_data7 = tuple(list(data7)[:2] + [tuple(list(data7[2])[:2] + ['7'] + list(data7[2])[3:])] + list(data7)[3:])

print(modified_data7)
```

Comment: No need for all those list casts. `(*data7[:2], (*data7[2][:2], '7', *data7[2][3:]), *data7[3:])`  is enough. Tuples may not be mutable, but they are absolutely slicable and concatenable.

Comment: @user2390182 I appreciate your suggestion!, In my previous response, I opted for converting the tuple to a list and back to a tuple as a way to make it more explicit and easy to follow the steps involved in modifying the tuple. While this approach might introduce some additional memory usage due to the temporary list, it provides a clear step-by-step process for beginners to understand the transformation.

Comment: Yeah, if you do all the conversion like in a comprehension and then do `data[2][2] = "7"` then it will be more readable. But, if you do it in a single step with slices, the conversions make it both less performant and less readable and obfuscate the fact that all those operations (slicing, cancatenating) can be done with tuples just as well.

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.